# php out of memory, array breaking into subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, out-of-memory

I am using an update function, where I insert some 40,000 rows to a mysql database. While making that array, I am getting out of memory error (tried to allocate 41 bytes).

The final function is like this:

```
function Tright($area) {
   foreach ($area as $a1=>&$a2) {
       mysql_query('INSERT INTO 0_right SET section=\''.$a2['sec_id'].'\', user_id=\''.$a2['user_id'].'\', rank_id=\''.$a2['rank_id'].'\', menu_id=\''.$a2['menu_id'].'\', droit = 1;');
   }
}
```

I have two questions. Is it natural that this above work load becomes too much for php to handle?

If no, can anyone suggest where should I check? And if yes, is there a way to break that $area array to subarrays and execute the function, maybe that way I won't get the out of memory issue. Any other workaround?

Thanks guys.

---

Edit: @halfdan, @Patrick Fisher, both of you have spoken about making a single multi insert query. How do you do that, in this example please.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Looping over SQL statements is generally very slow, you should probably to a multi insert. How much memory do you give your PHP instance?

Comment: Are you speaking about this one > http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/

Comment: I know this is long closed, but the problem was the foreach ($area as $a1=>&$a2) where the & will cause php to remember all $a2 arrays. And you don't even use the &

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should combine all the values into a single `INSERT` statement, instead of 40,000 different queries.

Second, yes, it is quite natural that you are running out of memory. You can increase this limit at runtime with `ini_set()`, e.g. `ini_set('memory_limit', '16M');`

---

To insert multiple values at once, your SQL should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO 0_right (section, user_id, rank_id, menu_id, droit) VALUES
(1,1,1,1,1),
(1,2,1,1,1),
(1,3,1,1,1)
```

You can build the query like so:

```
$values = '';
foreach ($area as $a){
    if ($values != ''){
        $values .= ',';
    }
    $values .= "('{$a['sec_id']}', '{$a['user_id']}', '{$a['rank_id']}', '{$a['menu_id']}',  1)";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO 0_right (section, user_id, rank_id, menu_id, droit) VALUES $values";
```

Comment: @atrick Fisher: How do I combine all the values into a single INSERT statement in this example, please?

Comment: Well @Patrick Fisher, on doing mysql_query, I'm getting `Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`

Comment: Solved with the server guys. ;)

Answer (score 1):

These are all nice answers to get around the problem.  If this is a one time script, just bump up the RAM and make sure the script doesn't time out (max_execution_time in the php.ini file) and you should be fine.

It may run faster if it was one big insert statement, but then you'd pay the cost of constructing the huge query on the PHP side (so the out of memory issue will still be there and will be even worse with the string concatenation).  But honestly, who cares if you're just running this once?

However, if you're to perform this operation all the time (e.g. on a webpage), I'd recommend other approaches... like restricting the size of the area, cutting the feature or storing the data differently.

Comment: Thanks @Saurav, I'll be using that a few times, moving one site to a new location, for the coding, debugging and testing phase. My new error is now `Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in (configurable) memory limit to prevent a single script that goes the wrong way from bogging down the whole machine. Depending on your version, that limit defaults to 8MB (pre-5.2.0), 16MB (5.2.0), or 128MB (5.3.0).

You can change the limit either via ini_set or in the php.ini.

Comment: It's 5.2.9 in my server. memory_limit: 128M.

Comment: @yes123: No idea, probably because they figured that RAM gets cheaper, applications deal with more data, and machines have abundant RAM because it's cheap. Personally I've never run into a memory limit, but then again my scripts deal with working sets of a dozen or so rows at most, never 40,000 at a time.